# Can Brexit be undone in an emergency?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, economy, financial-crisis, state-of-emergency

In case Brexit has already happened, can it be reversed after a short time?

Legally, the answer is no, I think.

But I can imagine a situation where, during the first few days after Brexit, all participants unanimously agree it should not have happened.

It is at least possible that the first days after Brexit create a crisis that makes all agree it went horribly wrong, and dangerously so.

From the EU side, let us assume it recognizes the crisis and is willing to cooperate in any way that its laws allow.

If all relevant politicians of all parties in the UK would **unanimously agree** that it lead to a **catastrophic crisis**, and should be **reverted at any cost** - is that possible in **any controlled way**?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel With all due respect, your scenarios are wildly fantastical. The UK is not going to "uncontrollably descend down to a failed state" or "go to war with the EU" in the first few days after Brexit, even in the worst case scenario.

Comment: @JBentley  Yes, that is all true. It is about covering all possibilities, even the ones that practically can not happen. The whole scenario is an academic construct to find out which parts can practically happen. That would be the practical worst case. The scenario is somehow the physical worst case.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Ok, but I don't think it matters. The solutions for the UK rejoining the EU are the same regardless of the reasons for rejoining. Namely, joining via Article 49, or rewriting the rules via treaty change (as per the two answers). Coming up with more and more extreme scenarios is in my opinion just distracting from the question, which is really "how can the UK rejoin the EU after Brexit and/or how quickly can that be done?". Or to put it another way, taking your title question "Can Brexit be undone in an emegency?", an answer would be "Yes, the same way as in a non-emergency."

Comment: @JBentley That's a good answer: Agree to handle the situation later according to Article 49 with acceptance of joining. Then undo the changes formally, and start to fix what was already broken since Brexit. It may be a lot, and complex. But it is known what happened.

Comment: Just about any agreement can be undone or recreated if all parties agree to do so, even when there are rules or laws standing in the way. But 4 rare things in politics are unanimous agreement, admitting to mistakes, speed and making exceptions.

Comment: About the only crisis that will occur is the one created when all the other EU countries realize how much better off the UK is after leaving the EU and they start wanting to do the same thing.

Comment: Another -1 for fantasizing that Brexit is some unimaginable instant disaster.

Comment: @RonJohn What is wrong about hypothetical scenarios?

Comment: @glglgl then we can hypothesize what would happen if John Bull and Athena come down from the clouds on the day after Brexit and restore the Empire and bring Ireland to heel.  Point being that unless you want politics.SE to devolve into partisan fantasy, limits must be maintained on the level of fantasy.

Comment: @RonJohn It is true that certain limits must be maintained, but it it is not very unlikely that things start to get uneasy (at least for a time, until solutions are found) after a Brexit. Let's hope, though, that things can be fixed then.

Comment: @glglgl "things start to get uneasy" is **substantively different from** what the Questioner wrote: "the first days after Brexit create a crisis that makes all agree it went horribly wrong, and dangerously so." and "If all relevant politicians of all parties in the UK would **unanimously agree** that it lead to a **catastrophic crisis**, and should be **reverted at any cost**" (emphasis his, not mine).

Comment: @RonJohn The idea is to think about what would happen if it starts to get really bad, not just uneasy. If it's just uneasy, the question does not apply. Nothing special would happen in that case, it is just one of the anticipated outcomes, easy, uneasy or great. Maybe even very uneasy. I'm saying that even then, the possibly dramatic things discussed are not relevant. It's about excluding the case of "It gets very uneasy or bad", so "dramatic things" happen. It is about what would happen if it, for unexpected reasons, gets worse than anticipated. I do not expect that to happen, by definition.

Answer (score 50):

"Can it happen"?  Sure, the laws of the EU are set by the members of the EU, if the members want to change the rules they can. They can re-admit the UK or not. If there is a law against it, the EU can just change the law. With sufficient political will on both sides it is possible.

"Will it happen"? After years of causing problems, how likely is it that the political will would exist?

Comment: While I do agree with what you're saying, the answer would be a lot better with some background sources that support your argument. It also answers a question with another question "how likely is it that the political will would exist?", instead of explaining why there is or isn't a chance for the political will to exist. As is, it reads like a comment.

Comment: @Peter: That would be answering a different question. *This* question assumes the EU "recognizes the crisis and is willing to cooperate in any way that its laws allow." Changing the laws is allowed by the laws, so this is a complete answer.

Comment: I think this answer is fine, but to add to @peter's point it might be worth explaining that the solution this answer describes is by way of treaty change, which can be done by unanimous agreement of the member states. "Change the rules" and "change the law" is a bit ambiguous as it could be referring to treaties, regulations, directives, etc. (and only the former applies here).

Comment: The EU cannot just change the laws that govern it.  This would, at the very least, require votes in all the parliaments, possibly referenda in multiple countries, and would certainly result in legal challenges at the highest level in courts all over Europe.  This would likely take longer than than the process for seeking membership by normal means.  It would also require the UK to realign it's laws to the EU, the very issue they want to leave over (if you take the Brexiter talk at face value, which I personally don't).  The practicalities make it impossible to implement quickly as well.

Comment: The commision can't change the Law, but neither the commision, nor the parliament is the EU. The EU is the union of the countries. By the consent of all the countries of the EU any EU treaty can be changed.  However treaty change is not required to re-admit a country, only the approval of the European council.

Comment: Considering that in 2017, Jean-Claude Junker told the German Newspaper "Bild" that "Britain will be made an example of", I don't think that the Political Will ever existed...

Comment: @JamesK The answer by Martin Schröder includes the quote "the adjustments to the Treaties" - sounds like treaty change *is* required, and that cannot be done quickly.

Comment: @Chronocidal readmission underlines the folly of leaving.

Answer (score 26):

**No**. But the UK can apply for membership according to [Article 49 of the Treaty on the European Union](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A12016M049). This normally takes years. The article text:

> Any European State which respects the values referred to in Article 2 and is committed to promoting them may apply to become a member of the Union. The European Parliament and national Parliaments shall be notified of this application. The applicant State shall address its application to the Council, which shall act unanimously after consulting the Commission and after receiving the consent of the European Parliament, which shall act by a majority of its component members. The conditions of eligibility agreed upon by the European Council shall be taken into account.
>
> The conditions of admission and the adjustments to the Treaties on which the Union is founded, which such admission entails, shall be the subject of an agreement between the Member States and the applicant State. This agreement shall be submitted for ratification by all the contracting States in accordance with their respective constitutional requirements.

Comment: And then they will enter with much worse terms they had while they were in. As founding members, they had some special privileges, which they will not receive again if they apply in the future as a new member candidate.

Comment: @vsz UK was not a founding member of the EEG. Germany, France, Italy, Netherlands, Belgium and Luxembourg are.

Comment: @Sjoerd : then under what kind of "early joiner" program did the UK receive those privileges so many people are talking about?

Comment: @vsz At one of the many treaty changes that introduces new elements, the UK asked for an opt-out. As did Denmark, and I think Ireland as well (and maybe others). But that's not the only way: The rebate was "earned" in 1984 when UK threatened to paralyze the EC with vetoes - everything requires unanimity at that time - until they got their rebate.

Comment: @vsz You are right that those privileges will not automatically be reinstated when rejoining. But they could, as part of the negotiations, if enough countries are willing to accept those privileges again. (Which is highly unlikely to happen, though)

Comment: @Sjoerd No privileges will be given. And the pound will have to go.

Comment: @MartinSchröder The pound would have to go? Why would the UK be expected to enter on worse terms than new member states currently?

Comment: @MartinSchröder the way the "convergence critera" work make Euro membership effectively optional; countries have to sign up to "work towards" it, but not at any particular rate. Recently joined Croatia is still using the Kuna, for example. This is one of those things where the UK government spent a lot of time misleading people during the Scottish referendum and then found it backfired.

Comment: @pjc50 I know; Sweden and Poland are doing the same.

Comment: @pjc50 at the moment, it would not be a good opportunity to force the issue, but deliberately breaking the convergence criteria is not going to be accepted indefinitely. Only the UK and Denmark have the permanent opt-out.

Comment: Re the Euro - one of the reasons that the UK never wanted to join is that it intially did - the ERM was an early attempt at going towards that goal, and they learned their lesson (both with regards to the problems of being shackled to rate, and the amount of help they could expect from other EC members in case of said problems arising)

Comment: @JBentley because it will have to be accepted by the other EU member states (and the EU parliament) per article 49 TEU. I don't think many newer members which didn't get exceptions and special deals will be too eager to give the UK what they themselves didn't get. That said, they may well allow the UK to keep their currency, but probably won't reinstate [the rebate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_rebate#Pressure_for_change).

Comment: @JJJ My point was that newer members have retained their currencies, so this wouldn't be an example of the UK getting "what they themselves didn't get".

Comment: @JBentley When the UK is a member of the EU again after a Brexit, it will get *no special* treatment. Scotland (which will already be a member) will make sure of that.

Comment: @MartinSchröder At the risk of repeating myself, allowing the UK to retain the pound is *not* special treatment by the standards of newer members, who have all kept their currencies. Also your comment includes far too many speculations on top of what is already a hypothetical scenario (that Scotland will be independent, that it will join the EU, that it will do so before the UK, etc.)

Answer (score 11):

The problem with "what if" is that anything goes.

If they find unobtanium under the hills of Wales which clearly would yield trillions of euro of profit every year but requires ten trillion euros to invest first which clearly requires an all European effort, you *bet* everyone would very, *very* quickly find which half of the toast is buttered. Amend the Lisbon treaty? That can be done in weeks if there is a concentrated will. Yes, you can run referendums if necessary extraordinarily quick if you really badly want to.

Lacking a miracle like that, what catastrophe can hit that would mould the will of some half a billion people into a single unit all of a sudden? Perhaps widespread, immediate threat of famine could do it but last I checked Britain was not exactly the breadbasket of Europe.

Comment: how long is a piece of string?

Comment: In the UK we are told that a new referendum would take at least nine months.

Comment: Even under current legislation it wouldn't (PPERA specifies a ten week minimum campaign period and there's no other relevant law) but if we are in fantasy land, laws can be amended really quick (see how fast some legislation went through both houses just the other week).

Comment: Even assuming the unobtanium scenario, the UK might get those trillions as loan (or joint venture) from the US... In reality, rejoining the EU would require the UK population to no longer assume that the Polish plumbers are an existential (economical, of course) threat.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "no", but the UK would have a good chance of joining EFTA (the European Free Trade Association) quickly (the "Norway solution"). This would give the UK many of the benefits of being in the EU without the worst of the negatives.

Comment: This is speculation, and Norway has indicated they oppose this. Basically the UK's behavior in the EU has caused a wide distrust of the UK. If anything, they'd be admitted as a non-voting member.

Comment: Disregarding the fact that, no, they won't have a good chance of joining EFTA, doing this would give the UK less benefits of being in the EU, with more of the negatives than they had as the special, privileged member that they were.